# Getting an elements children IDs in selenium python

Tags: python, list, selenium, element, children

I'm having some issues getting the div id's from an element I have scraped.
Let's say this is the website code in the area I have pulled via class name "products"

There are id's also in the children of these listed id's I do not want those. Nor the ones on the full page.

```
<div class = "products">
   <div> 
        <div> id= "123">...</div>
        <div> id= "456">...</div>
        <div> id= "789">...</div>
        <div> id= "012">...</div>
   </div>
```

Here is my selenium/python code. I've tried several solutions but I've been unable to find the answer.

```
driver.get("https://genericwebsite.org")

scrape = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'products')


# Here are some solutions I've tried to no avail


ids = scrape.find_elements(By.XPATH, "./child::*").get_attribute('id')



# This one pulls ALL IDS from the children's children as well as maybe the full sites.  

ids = scrape.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id]' )
```

I've tried many iterations but can't seem to find the solution.
My desired result is as follows:

```
ids = ["123", "456", "789", "012]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
ids = []
scrape = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, '//div[@class=\'products\']/div/div')

for item in scrape:
    ids.append(item.get_attribute('id'))

print(ids)
```

with this code you enter each and every `div` mentioned above and get their respective id with `get_attribute` method and append it to the `ids list`

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was gonna be something simple I was missing. I really appreciate it.